# Can shopify 3rd party apps be used from custom frontend app?

Tags: shopify

I have a website which I want to integrate with shopify using shopify as backend **only**. I know there are sdks like js buy sdk and I can even use storefront api directly. The question is can I use shopify store apps (for example [advanced product options](https://apps.shopify.com/advanced-product-options) ) with it ?

Comment: You can't use  advanced product options app, you should have both shopify backend and frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading docs and even directly contacting with the apps team and shopify teams I found out we can't since the apps provide embeddable ui components which necessarily required liquid.